# i wanted to name myself a Japanese name,(first-last) but i wanted to know if it was okay to do so

Tags: meaning, word-choice, pronunciation, names, honorifics

Can someone please answer my question somehow? I would like to respect and honor the means of Japanese people/culture. I did not want to name myself a Japanese name without permission from the Japanese first.

Comment: There is no official "blessing" you will get from a Japanese person that will make it ok or not, if you look caucasian, and present yourself with a Japanese name. Some people would be surprised, some would be happy, some might not like as much. But Japanese people do that a lot when abroad too (because people can't pronounce their Japanese names)... though if we are talking about the legal aspect, if you get Japanese citizenship, you can actually change your name for a fully Japanese one that will be printed in all your official documents, etc.

Comment: There isn't any way to obtain permission from "the Japanese" for something like this, though there may be some venue on the internet where you could solicit opinions from **individual** Japanese people about how they would feel about your taking a Japanese name. This isn't really the place for that, though. (For what it's worth, as a non-Japanese person who has lived in Japan I can tell you that it is **not** at all common for foreigners there to adopt new Japanese names, or even Japanese approximations of their real names. Kim Smith becomes Kimu Sumisu, not Tanaka Yōko or Shimizu Kimiko.)

Comment: Sorry, i didn't mean to word it that way. I know usual Japanese names go (last-first name) but i wanted mine the opposite. I just didnt want to go forth and do something if it wasnt okay for Japanese people or if they were uncomfortable with it. I wanted a Japanese name for a reason, mostly because of my family history, although i am not Japanese nor Caucasian. Im Native American.

Comment: I think you're right to wonder how Japanese people might react to this idea, and the fact that you care about that speaks well of you. But I'm afraid your question might be closed as off-topic for this site because it isn't really about the Japanese language, as such. (Continued below)

Comment: There might be a better place to try to gain some insight into this issue, either on Stack Exchange or on some other site. If you do find such a place, it might also be helpful if you could give more detail on why you'd like to have a Japanese name and how and where you plan to use it. (From what you've written here, it's not clear whether you're talking about a legal name change, an entirely private nickname for yourself, or something in between.) Good luck!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When stating a non-Japanese name, should the surname come first?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/36399/when-stating-a-non-japanese-name-should-the-surname-come-first)